# Pinch/zoom scroll around image on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've searched around for lots of different jQuery libraries to add pinch/zoom functionality for mobile devices (like [touchy.js](https://github.com/HotStudio/touchy), [PhotoSwipe](http://photoswipe.com/), [TouchSwipe](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/index.html), [hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/) etc.) but I don't know what I should be looking for to solve this particular issue.

I need to create a simple game, very similar to "Where's Waldo?", where the user is giving a large image to scroll around (almost like Google maps), trying to find an item. When they find it, I need to take their "tap" co-ords -- taking into account the zoom level -- and see if they're right.

I feel like there's probably a library somewhere that already does 90% of what I need out of the box, but I don't know what this functionality is called. Is there such a library for this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the built-in pinch zoom feature? This would save you from having to do extraneous position calculations, touch listeners, etc.

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 0.1,maximum-scale = 1.0" />`

Comment: is `user-scalable=yes` optional?

Comment: Scaling is the default behavior.